# working with ApplicationContext but not with XmlBeanFactory

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

Below is what I tried with `ApplicationCOntext` and it works fine:

```
ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("spring-context.xml");
    Employee empl = (Employee)context.getBean("employee");
    System.out.println(empl.getName());
```

The same thing I tried with XMLBeanFactory and it did not worked:

```
XmlBeanFactory factory = new XmlBeanFactory
            (new ClassPathResource("spring-context.xml"));
    Employee obj = (Employee) factory.getBean("employee");
    System.out.println(obj.getName());
```

**Employee.java**

```
@Component
public class Employee {
@Value(value="XXX")
private String name;

public String getName() {
    return name;
}
}
```

Below is the xml file entry:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.XXX" />
```

Please advise why does `XMLBeanFactory` approach does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because XMLBeanFactory can only instantiate beans, it ignores `<context:...` elements. Find more details here http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#context-introduction-ctx-vs-beanfactory